# Removing rows with '0' values from a table generated by 'univariateTable'

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I have a table consisting of dummy variables (1's and 0's) like this one:

```
colnames<-c("gender","alpha","beta","gamma","delta","lambda")
row1<-c("male",0,1,0,1,0)
row2<-c("male",1,0,1,1,0)
row3<-c("female",1,0,1,0,0)
row4<-c("male",0,1,1,0,1)
row5<-c("female",0,1,0,1,0)
row6<-c("male",1,1,0,1,0)
df<-as.data.frame(rbind(row1,row2,row3,row4,row5,row6))
names(df)<-colnames
rownames(df) <- NULL
```

I formed this into a table using library 'Publish' on Github

```
library(Publish)
univariateTable(gender~alpha+beta+gamma+delta+lambda,data=df)
```

The output contains both 1's and 0's in the rows, but I only want 1's for obvious reasons

```
   Variable Level female (n=2) male (n=4) Total (n=6) p-value
1     alpha     0     1 (50.0)   2 (50.0)    3 (50.0)        
2               1     1 (50.0)   2 (50.0)    3 (50.0)       1
3      beta     0     1 (50.0)   1 (25.0)    2 (33.3)        
4               1     1 (50.0)   3 (75.0)    4 (66.7)       1
5     gamma     0     1 (50.0)   2 (50.0)    3 (50.0)        
6               1     1 (50.0)   2 (50.0)    3 (50.0)       1
7     delta     0     1 (50.0)   1 (25.0)    2 (33.3)        
8               1     1 (50.0)   3 (75.0)    4 (66.7)       1
9    lambda     0    2 (100.0)   3 (75.0)    5 (83.3)        
10              1      0 (0.0)   1 (25.0)    1 (16.7)       1
```

Obviously, I can go ahead and remove manually all the odd rows but I was wondering if there was an automated way to do that.

And also, ideally, it would be nice to get rid of the "level" column at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
cbind(subset(df,level=0,Variable),subset(df,level=1,3:6))
```

I'm putting side by side the Variable column, as a subset of the df with level =0, and the subset of columns 3 to 6 of the df, this time filered on level = 1.